# How to put bullet between items?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have some list-items from an ng-repeat from Angular.

I'm trying to put a bullet point between two items but it keeps putting it after the items.

Currently looks like

> Venue1‏• $20

I need it to look like

> Venue1 [bullet] $20

HTML:

`<h4 class="venue">{{show.properties.venue}}‏&bull;&nbsp;{{show.properties.price}}</h4>`

Why does the bullet get pushed to the end?

Comment: Very unlikely Can you setup a jsfiddle or plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/DkQFkNzTIuURzon2Jzp1?p=preview

Comment: you could probably use .venue:after with css generated content as a work around

Comment: Is there HTML in the bound data, like <span>$10</span>?

Comment: Or use `&middot;` instead.

Comment: Works fine.. http://plnkr.co/edit/VCFAQH?p=preview You have an rlm (Right-to-left) `&rlm;` mark right before the `&bull;` Just remove it.

Comment: You might have got it while copying `&bull;` from somewhere which would have contained the unicode.  http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html

Comment: @PSL, make that an answer, but without using the notation `&rlm;`, since the RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK is there as a character (invisible), not as an entity reference.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thats a valid point it was an invisible control char that OP might have inherited while Ctrl+c from somewhere i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `&bull;` it will display as you expect to have presented inside and between your interpolations. But you do have an invisible control character in your html just before the bullet. You may have inherited it from somewhere which represents the **[right-left-mark](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html)** which is specifically used to represent the mix of left-->right (ex:- English) and right --> left (ex:- Arabic/Hebrew) sentences. That caused the string after the invisible version of `&rlm;` characters (since it has only special chars and numbers, not English alphabets) to represent from right to left. Just strip it out and char and you should be good. If you suspect anything out of ordinary inspect your html in these kind of situations just inspect your rendered html (You cannot hide it from the browser :)).

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBRFwp?p=preview)**

[Some general info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark)

Comment: Strange, it was an invisible character.  Deleting it and typing it out myself (vs. copying from browser) solved it.  Thanks for the plunk and answer.